# Getting the latest timestamp in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join, timestamp

I am trying to create a report that has the latest member id in the first column and the old member id in the second column based on the timestamp in audits table below. Member ids are stored in master table and the members table. audit_id from the audits table is a foreign key in members table.

I tried to write the query below after researching but I am getting syntax errors.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT mem.member_id
   FROM members mem
   JOIN audits aud ON mem.audit_id = aud.audit_id
   ORDER BY aud.update_time DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY) AS latest_id,
       mem1.member_id AS old_id
FROM members mem1
JOIN master ma ON ma.member_id = mem1.member_id
```

**audits**

```
audit_id |update_time 
656566   |2021-01-15 17:01:34
656565   |2020-05-13 17:01:34
545245   |2020-08-11 17:01:34
```

**members**

```
member_id  |audit_id
5655656    |656566
653363     |656565
545454     |545245
```

**master**

```
id | member_id
545634 | 5655656
545634 | 653363
545634 | 545454
```

**Expected output**

```
latest_id | old_id
5655656    |653363
5655656    |545454
```

Comment: what happens f you have 5 entry or 10. Do you stiil expect only 2 results?

Comment: I expect more than 2 and all the old IDs in the second column with the latest id in the first column.

Comment: and what error message do you get? please add this  to your post

Comment: for showing us the expected rsult it would make sense to choose the different id types from different number ranges, e.g. all audits ids start with 1, all  mebers ids start wih 2, all master ids start with 3

Comment: "I tried to write the query below after researching but I am getting syntax errors."..... and are we to guess what the errors are?  Help us to help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

With A `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER` in conhunction with `Cross JOIN` you can get your wanted result.

The CTE creates a temporary table, which has the row number for all all master ids and of course the wanted member id.

The `SELECT`makes a Cartesian product of the first (latest) member id and the rest of the rows(member ids) for every master id

> ```
> CREATE TABLE master
>     ("id" int, "member_id" int)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT ALL 
>     INTO master ("id", "member_id")
>          VALUES (545634, 5655656)
>     INTO master ("id", "member_id")
>          VALUES (545634, 653363)
>     INTO master ("id", "member_id")
>          VALUES (545634, 545454)
> SELECT * FROM dual
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE members
>     ("member_id" int, "audit_id" int)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT ALL 
>     INTO members ("member_id", "audit_id")
>          VALUES (5655656, 656566)
>     INTO members ("member_id", "audit_id")
>          VALUES (653363, 656565)
>     INTO members ("member_id", "audit_id")
>          VALUES (545454, 545245)
> SELECT * FROM dual
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE audits
>     ("audit_id" int, "update_time" DATE )
> ;
> ```

> ```
> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
> ```

> ```
> INSERT ALL 
>     INTO audits ("audit_id", "update_time")
>          VALUES (656566, '2021-01-15 17:01:34')
>     INTO audits ("audit_id", "update_time")
>          VALUES (656565, '2020-05-13 17:01:34')
>     INTO audits ("audit_id", "update_time")
>          VALUES (545245, '2020-08-11 17:01:34')
> SELECT * FROM dual;
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (SELECT ma."id",me."member_id",
>    Row_NUMBER() OVER (
>         PARTITION BY ma."id"
>         ORDER BY "update_time" ASC
>                 ) "rn"
> from master ma 
>     INNER JOIN members me on ma."member_id" = me."member_id"
>     INNER JOIN audits au ON me."audit_id" = au."audit_id")
> SELECT a."member_id", b."member_id"
> FROM (SELECT "member_id","id" FROM CTE WHERE "rn"= 1) a 
> CROSS JOIN (SELECT "member_id","id", "rn" FROM CTE WHERE "rn" > 1)  b 
> WHERE a."id" = b."id"
> ORDER BY b."rn";
> ```
>
> ```
> member_id | member_id
> --------: | --------:
>    653363 |    545454
>    653363 |   5655656
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=993eb6a446d87e2d4046817345d0f3fa)*